# When do I need to use a Bigarray and why?

Tags: arrays, ocaml

The documentation on the Bigarray module is somewhat vague.  It states that the purpose of arrays in that module is to hold "large arrays", but it doesn't really define what it means by "large array".  When should I use a Bigarray over a regular array?  Is there a certain number of elements beyond which I should just use a Bigarray?  Is it in the thousands?  Millions?  Billions?

And what makes a Bigarray better at dealing with big arrays?  What makes a regular array better at dealing with... non-big arrays?

Comment: It may be that it's defining a 'big array' as a 'sparse array', though I'm completely ignorant of OCaml, so I could be waaaay off here.

Comment: Even in that case, why would you need a different data structure?

Comment: A sparse array doesn't (necessarily) hold a space in memory, or even a pointer to `null` for every element in the array. If you have an array of 2 billion elements as you suggest in your question, that's some 8GB worth, purely in pointers. If you only have 5 items actually in the array though (presumably at high indexes), then your storage space only really needs to hold 5 pointers and take up a handful of bytes.

Comment: If you actually have 2 billion items in your array though, then it doesn't matter whether it's a sparse array or a normal array though, you're equally screwed and need to look at a new way of storing your data.

Comment: @Matt - Wow, that makes total sense.  I'm surprised I hadn't heard of sparse arrays before.  But then again, I don't usually do that kind of programming.  :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the answer to this (from [this page](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual043.html)):

The bigarray library implements large, multi-dimensional, numerical arrays. These arrays are called “big arrays” to distinguish them from the standard Caml arrays described in Module Array. The main differences between “big arrays” and standard Caml arrays are as follows:

- Big arrays are not limited in size, unlike Caml arrays (float array are limited to 2097151 elements on a 32-bit platform, other array types to 4194303 elements).
- Big arrays are multi-dimensional. Any number of dimensions between 1 and 16 is supported. In contrast, Caml arrays are mono-dimensional and require encoding multi-dimensional arrays as arrays of arrays.
- Big arrays can only contain integers and floating-point numbers, while Caml arrays can contain arbitrary Caml data types. However, big arrays provide more space-efficient storage of integer and floating-point elements, in particular because they support “small” types such as single-precision floats and 8 and 16-bit integers, in addition to the standard Caml types of double-precision floats and 32 and 64-bit integers.
- The memory layout of big arrays is entirely compatible with that of arrays in C and Fortran, allowing large arrays to be passed back and forth between Caml code and C / Fortran code with no data copying at all.
- Big arrays support interesting high-level operations that normal arrays do not provide efficiently, such as extracting sub-arrays and “slicing” a multi-dimensional array along certain dimensions, all without any copying.

Comment: The compatibility with C/Fortran is the big case I see for bigarrays.  It can drastically reduce memory usage when interfacing with C or Fortran array-based libraries (e.g. BLAS).

Comment: The size limit is 16Mb and affects float arrays, int arrays and strings (which are byte arrays). Big arrays are used to allow large arrays on 32-bit platforms. Your best bit is to use a 64-bit platform and forget about big arrays...